# 429 error in here maps API calculateroute.json

Tags: here-maps-rest, http-status-code-429

I'm using calculateroute.json api, but now is 3 day, when I get `{"issues":[{"message":"Too many requests, please try again after some time"},{"message":"Request id: 2a2d34fa-612b-4a1c-9ac5-fdba3144015f"}],"error_id":"2a2d34fa-612b-4a1c-9ac5-fdba3144015f","response_code":"429 Too Many Requests"}` error. 
Full request (without auth) - https://fleet.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=60.953800,24.487190;100&detail=1&waypoint1=60.458140,22.035720;100&routelegattributes=li&routeattributes=wp,sc,sh,li&maneuverattributes=none&linkattributes=none,rt,fl&legattributes=none,li,sm&tollPass=transponder,Senior_Pass&currency=EUR&departure=&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&hybrid=0&emissionType=6&fuelType=diesel&height=4m&trailerHeight=400&vehicleWeight=12000&limitedWeight=40t&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&hov=0&passengersCount=1&tiresCount=12&commercial=1&heightAbove1stAxle=1m&width=2.55&length=16.5&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled;boatFerry:0&rollups=none,country;tollsys,country
Request limit per month not reached.
Where can be a problem?

Answer (score -1):

That means requests are being sent from the same source IP (i.e machine is very short time span of milliseconds)

Often it is worthwhile re-trying the request as the followup request may succeed when the original failed.

However, it is important NOT to simply loop repeatedly making requests to HERE's servers. This looping behavior can overload the network between your client and HERE causing problems for many parties.

A better approach is to retry with increasing DELAYS between attempts. Usually the delay is increased by a multiplicative factor with each attempt.